# About log4net config

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, log4net

I have debugged the code leaving to us from a vendor for several months. Till today I just find that the log4net configuration still contains vendor's information.
My simple question:
Does the vendor can track and record my work during the period? Is it secure for my pasted work?
What is the smtpHost IP?

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="somebody@some_vendor.com"/>
  <from value="person@some_vendor.com"/>
  <subject value="Company Portal"/>
  <smtpHost value="xy.a.b.cd"/>
  <authentication value="Basic"/>
  <username value="somebody@some_vendor.com"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it isn't secure, because if your application has internet access and smtphost is available and works, then everything, that logger is supposed to log will be mailed to developer.
 Look through the code, what type of messages are loged?

smtphost is dns name for machine that provides stmp service, for sending emails.

Comment: Ok. How can I quickly to find my smtphost? Usually the error message is logged in try catch block.

Comment: look through config file, get the value for smtphost, and check if it is available from your pc via [domw.net](http://domw.net) service.

Answer (score 1):

The smtpHost is the ip or domain of the smtp server to use when the SmtpAppender is called.
So any level configured to be logged using the smtpappender generates an email using that smtpserver as host.
The server your code is running on has to be able to connect to xy.a.b.cd in order to be able to send messages.